# ArrayList adicionando valores indevidos

Tags: java, array

Tenho um `ArrayList` que deveria estar recebendo números de 0 a 15, dentro de um `for`, porém parece que está ficando gravado em todos os índices o último valor 15.

```
ArrayList <PaginaPrincipalSO> FilaTPSO= new ArrayList();
PaginaPrincipalSO TPSO = new PaginaPrincipalSO();

public void armazenarTPSO(PaginaPrincipalSO a){
    FilaTPSO.add(a);
}

public void preencherTPSO(){
    int NPF = retornaNPF();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, NPF); //apenas para confirmar o valor de NPF que chega como 15
    for(int y=0;y<=NPF;y++){
        TPSO.setNPF(y);
        armazenarTPSO(TPSO);
    }
    for(int y=0;y<=NPF;y++){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, FilaTPSO.get(y).getNPF()); //buscando os valores dentro do arraylist e recebendo como retorno sempre 15
    }

}
```

Comment: Não estou vendo nenhum problema. Será que não está em algum ponto do código que você não está mostrando? Está criando 16 elementos no *array*?

Comment: O problema é que ele adiciona sempre o mesmo objeto, ao invés de instanciar um a cada iteração.

Comment: isto, são 16 elementos. Justamente estou colocando aqui, pois não parecer ter erros e esta parte do código independe das outras a princípio. Mas quando rodo o último FOR recebo sempre 15.

Comment: Você acha que teria que fazer isto a cada interação:

   PaginaPrincipalSO TPSO = new PaginaPrincipalSO();

Comment: CORRETO @Wakin. Funcionou... Como agradeço sua resposta, já que foi um comentário?

Comment: @Wakim boa, comi bola nesta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema é que está adicionando e alterando sempre o mesmo objeto na lista, isto é, está com um vetor de 16 posições apontando para o mesmo objeto.

O correto seria instanciar e inicializar um novo objeto em cada iteração, para que sua lógica não sobrescreva o valor dos objetos.

Seu código deveria ficar:

```
public void preencherTPSO(){
    int NPF = retornaNPF();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, NPF); //apenas para confirmar o valor de NPF que chega como 15
    PaginaPrincipalSO localTPSO;

    for(int y=0;y<=NPF;y++){
        // Inicializa um novo Objeto para adicionar na lista.
        localTPSO = new PaginaPrincipalSO();

        localTPSO.setNPF(y);
        armazenarTPSO(localTPSO);
    }

    for(int y=0;y<=NPF;y++){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, FilaTPSO.get(y).getNPF()); //buscando os valores dentro do arraylist e recebendo como retorno sempre 15
    }
}
```

E não precisa manter uma instância global mais.

Comment: Obrigado.... :D